# Javascript Form Validation on submition overvalidating

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am currently stuck on the issue on developing a working JavaScript Validation for  Form i have created. The issue with it is that when i have submitted it the first time with ony the first Name entered it then discovers that the rest is not filled out what is needed and spits out an error what Needs to be filled out. but when i then send the form a secnd time it then adds to the error Messages same error Messages at the end and so on.
Also it then when i try to enter the Last Name it then doesnt validate the rest to check if they are filled out correct.

the Error message i am getting when pressing the submitt button is (ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO comeandtry (Fname, Lname, Email, Gender, Phone, Day, Month, Year, Street, Subburb, Zip, QrCode) VALUES ('a', '','','','','','','','','','','895971bd039060f94fa526e395b0c86a'). Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Phone' at row 1) which should not happen as there was only a value in First Name and the rest should not go through the Validation :/

```js
var errorStr = "" //initialize the errorStr
var trueOrFalse = true

function validate() {
  //initialises all of the variables which are going to be used
  //alert("hello")

  var character = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"
  var temp2
  var difnumbers = "0123456789"
  var temp3

  x = document.registration

  validateFname(x);
  //alert("a")
  validateLname(x);
  //alert("c")
  validateEmail(x);
  //alert("d")
  validateGender(x);
  //alert("e")
  validatePhone(x);
  //alert("f")
  //validateDOB(x);
  //alert("g")
  validateStreet(x);
  //alert("h")
  validateSubburb(x);
  //alert("i")
  validateZipCode(x);
  //alert("j")
  validateCheckBox(x);

  //this will display all of the error messages at the same time.
  if (!trueOrFalse) {
    alert(errorStr);
  }
  //alert("end")

  return trueOrFalse
}

function validateFname(x) {
  //Vallidation for the Firstname
  if (x.Fname.value == "") {
    {
      errorStr = errorStr + "It seems like you havn't entered you're First Name. Please have another look.\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < x.Fname.value.length; i++) {
      temp2 = x.Fname.value.substring(i, i + 1)
      if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
        errorStr = errorStr + "It looks like you have entered a non Alphabetical character into you're First Name.\n\n"
        trueOrFalse = false
      }
    }
  }
}

function validateLname(x) {
  if (x.Lname.value == "") {
    errorStr = errorStr + "It seems like you havn't entered you're Last Name. Please have another look.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Lname.value.length; i++) {
    temp2 = x.Lname.value.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
      errorStr = errorStr + "It looks like you have entered a non Alphabetical character into you're Last Name.\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
  }
}

function validateEmail(x) {
  var test = x.Email.value.indexOf("@")
  //if didn't find @
  if (test == -1) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "Please enter a valid E-Mail.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  //if @ is the first character
  if (test == 0) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "The E-Mail you have Entered is not valid. The '@' can't be the first Character.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  //if @ is the last character
  if (test == (x.Email.value.length - 1)) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "The E-Mail you have Entered is not valid. The '@' can't be the last Character.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
}

function validateGender(x) {
  if (!x.Gender[0].checked && !x.Gender[1].checked) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "Please select a gender\n\n"

    trueOrFalse = false
  }
}

function validatePhone(x) {
  //validation for the mobile number
  if (x.Phone.value == "") {
    errorStr = errorStr + "You haven't inputted a phone number (e.g. 0420 111 111.)\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  if (x.Phone.value.length != 10) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "please input a valid number length(10 Digits).\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Phone.value.length; i++) {
    temp3 = x.Phone.value.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (difnumbers.indexOf(temp3) == -1) {
      errorStr = errorStr + "Sorry, you have entered non valid Phone number. Please enter only numbers.\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
  }
}

function validateStreet(x) {
  //this validates the city
  if (x.Street.value == "") {
    errorStr = errorStr + "You haven't entered your Street, please enter your Street.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Street.value.length; i++) {
    temp2 = x.Street.value.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
      errorStr = errorStr + "Sorry, you have entered a number. Your Street cannot contain a number. Please re-enter .\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
  }
}

function validateSubburb(x) {
  //this part checks the street upon its entered values
  if (x.Subburb.value == "") {
    errorStr = errorStr + "You haven't entered your Street name, please enter your Subburb.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Subburb.value.length; i++) {
    temp2 = x.Subburb.value.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
      errorStr = errorStr + "Sorry, you have entered a number. Your Street name cannot contain a number. Please re-enter your Subburb.\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
  }
}

function validateZipCode(x) {
  //validation for the mobile number
  if (x.Zip.value == "") {
    errorStr = errorStr + "You haven't inputted a Zip Code (e.g. 0420.)\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  if (x.Zip.value.length != 4) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "please input a valid Zip Code length(4 Digits).\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Zip.value.length; i++) {
    temp3 = x.Zip.value.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (difnumbers.indexOf(temp3) == -1) {
      errorStr = errorStr + "Sorry, you have entered non valid Zip Code. please enther only numbers.\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
  }
}

function validateCheckBox(x) {
  if (!x.terms.checked) {
    alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="container">
      <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <form name="registration" onsubmit="return validate()" action="add.php" method="post">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Fname" autofocus placeholder="Your first name..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Last Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Lname" placeholder="Your last name..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>E-mail</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Your Email..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Your Gender</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="radio" value="Male" name="Gender">Male
              <br>
              <input type="radio" value="Female" name="Gender">Female
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Phone Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Your D.O.B.:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-20">
              Day:<input type="text" name="Day" size="2" maxlength="2" placeholder="5"> Month:
              <input type="text" name="Month" size="2" maxlength="2" placeholder="10"> Year:
              <input type="text" name="Year" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="1995">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>What Hand are you?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="radio" value="Right" name="Hand">Right
              <br>
              <input type="radio" value="Left" name="Hand">Left
              <br>
              <input type="radio" value="Unknown" name="Hand">Unknown
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Street Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-20">
              <input type="text" name="StreetNumber" placeholder="Your Street Number..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Street Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Street" placeholder="Your Street Name..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Subburb</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Subburb" placeholder="Your Subburb..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Postcode</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Zip" placeholder="Your Postcode..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>State</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <select name="State">
          <option value="Victoria" selected>Victoria</option>
          <option value="SouthAustrailia">South Austrailia</option>
          <option value="WesternAustrailia">Western Austrailia</option>
          <option value="NorthernTerretory">Northern Terretory</option>
          <option value="Queensland">Queensland</option>
        </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>I Agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <label class="containerCheckBox">Agree 
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope on some Feedback.

Comment: Have you considered re-initializing the errorStr and trueOrFalse variables at the beginning of the main validation function logic?

Comment: @codemaker do u mean Setting the errorStr to empty? i have tryed this but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: There may be some issues in your other validation functions, but I would set the variables errorStr="" and trueOrFalse = true at the start of your main validation function (validate()), prior to calling any of the other validation functions.

Comment: so like this?
validate() { errorStr = "" ; trueOrFalse = true;} @codemaker

Comment: Yes, for starters.  I'm checking your other functions.

Comment: Can you provide the table definition for [comeandtry]?

Comment: ID Int Auto_increment;
Fname Varchar(255);
Lname Varchar(255);
Email Varchar(255);
Gender Varchar(255);
Phone int(11);
Day int(11);
Month int(11);
Year int(11);
Street Varchar(255);
Subburb varchar(255);
zip int(11);
qrCode Varchar(255);
@codemaker

Comment: What database management system are you using? (e.g. - SQL Server, MS-Access, mySQL).  Regardless, some fields do not need to be integers, even if they contain numeric data, they can be string types (varchar,etc).  Also, you may need to allow nulls for optional data fields.

Comment: WampServer for local host with MySql

Comment: @codemaker
thankyou for having a look what my mistake is

Comment: This is an example definition change (
  ID Int IDENTITY(1,1) OR Auto_Increment, 
  Fname Varchar(255),
  Lname Varchar(255),
  Email Varchar(255),
  Gender Varchar(255),
  Phone VARCHAR(11),
  Day int,
  Month int,
  Year int, 
  Street Varchar(255),
  Subburb varchar(255),
  zip VARCHAR(11),
  qrCode Varchar(255)
  )

Comment: have you created this table in a DB? im kinda stuck on how to create the identity(1,1)

Comment: Show me your SQL statement, if you are using one to create the table.  Perhaps, you could create a second table (e.g. - comeandtryTest).  Like CREATE TABLE comeandtryTest(
  ID Int IDENTITY(1,1), 
  Fname Varchar(255),
  Lname Varchar(255),
  Email Varchar(255),
  Gender Varchar(255),
  Phone VARCHAR(11),
  Day int,
  Month int,
  Year int, 
  Street Varchar(255),
  Subburb varchar(255),
  zip VARCHAR(11),
  qrCode Varchar(255)
  )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158622/discussion-between-mark-and-codemaker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, you might want to consider some of the more contemporary approaches to client side data validation (see @msanford's post).  Here is a variation on your initial approach.  I recommend data validation on both the client and server sides, but here is just the client side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var errorStr = ""; //initialize the errorStr
var validated = true;
var character = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz";
var difnumbers = "0123456789";
var temp2;
var temp3;


function validate(x) {
  //initialises all of the variables which are going to be used

  // Initialise Global variables with each call
  errorStr = "";
  validated = true;
  temp2 = "";
  temp3 = "";

  // This expression will evaluate to 0 if false, otherwise 1 if true 
  validated = ((validateFname(x) & validateLname(x) & validateEmail(x) & validateGender(x) & validatePhone(x) & validateStreet(x) & validateSubburb(x) & validateZipCode(x) & validateCheckBox(x))==1);


  //validateDOB(x); // If you add validation for this you may need to take into account LEAP YEARS and appropriate number ranges for Months (e.g. - February and 28,29,30, and 31 days in a particular month, etc.)

  //this will display all of the error messages at the same time.

  if (!validated) {
    alert(errorStr);
  }

  return validated;

}

function validateFname(x) {
  //Vallidation for the Firstname
  x.Fname.value = x.Fname.value.trim(); // Remove leading and trailing spaces
  if (x.Fname.value == "") {
      errorStr += "It seems like you haven't entered you're First Name. Please have another look.\n\n";
      return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < x.Fname.value.length; i++) {
      temp2 = x.Fname.value.substring(i, i+1);
      if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
        errorStr += "It looks like you have entered a non Alphabetical character into you're First Name.\n\n";
        return false;
      }
    }

  return true;
}

function validateLname(x) {
  x.Lname.value = x.Lname.value.trim(); // Remove leading and trailing spaces
  if (x.Lname.value == "") {
    errorStr += "It seems like you haven't entered you're Last Name. Please have another look.\n\n";
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Lname.value.length; i++) {
    temp2 = x.Lname.value.substring(i, i+1);
    if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
      errorStr +="It looks like you have entered a non Alphabetical character into you're Last Name.\n\n";
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function validateEmail(x) {
  x.Email.value = x.Email.value.trim(); // Remove leading and trailing spaces (May need to prohibit spaces altogether)
  var test = x.Email.value.indexOf("@")
  //if didn't find @
  if (test == -1) {
    errorStr += "Please enter a valid E-Mail.\n\n";
    return false;
  }
  //if @ is the first character
  if (test == 0) {
    errorStr += "The E-Mail you have Entered is not valid. The '@' can't be the first Character.\n\n";
    return false;
  }
  //if @ is the last character
  if (test == (x.Email.value.trim().length - 1)) {
    errorStr += "The E-Mail you have Entered is not valid. The '@' can't be the last Character.\n\n";
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function validateGender(x) {
  if (!x.Gender[0].checked && !x.Gender[1].checked) {
    errorStr += "Please select a gender\n\n";

    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function validatePhone(x) {
  //validation for the mobile number
  x.Phone.value = x.Phone.value.trim(); // Remove leading and trailing spaces
  if (x.Phone.value == "") {
    errorStr += "You haven't inputted a phone number (e.g. 0420 111 111.)\n\n";
    return false;
  }
  if (x.Phone.value.length != 10) {
    errorStr += "please input a valid number length(10 Digits).\n\n";
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Phone.value.length; i++) {
    temp3 = x.Phone.value.substring(i, i+1);
    if (difnumbers.indexOf(temp3) == -1) {
      errorStr += "Sorry, you have entered non valid Phone number. Please enter only numbers.\n\n";
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function validateStreet(x) {
  //this validates the city
  x.Street.value = x.Street.value.trim(); // Remove leading and trailing spaces
  if (x.Street.value == "") {
    errorStr += "You haven't entered your Street, please enter your Street.\n\n";
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Street.value.length; i++) {
    temp2 = x.Street.value.substring(i, i+1);
    if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
      errorStr += "Sorry, you have entered a number. Your Street cannot contain a number. Please re-enter .\n\n";
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function validateSubburb(x) {
  //this part checks the street upon its entered values
  x.Subburb.value = x.Subburb.value.trim(); // Remove leading and trailing spaces
  if (x.Subburb.value == "") {
    errorStr += "You haven't entered your Suburb, please enter your Suburb.\n\n";
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Subburb.value.length; i++) {
    temp2 = x.Subburb.value.substring(i, i+1);
    if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
      errorStr += "Sorry, you have entered a number. Your Suburb name cannot contain a number. Please re-enter your Suburb.\n\n";
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function validateZipCode(x) {
  //validation for the mobile number
  x.Zip.value = x.Zip.value.trim(); // Remove leading and trailing spaces
  if (x.Zip.value == "") {
    errorStr += "You haven't inputted a Zip Code (e.g. 0420.)\n\n";
    return false;
  }
  if (x.Zip.value.trim().length != 4) {
    errorStr += "please input a valid Zip Code length(4 Digits).\n\n";
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Zip.value.length; i++) {
    temp3 = x.Zip.value.substring(i, i+1);
    if (difnumbers.indexOf(temp3) == -1) {
      errorStr += "Sorry, you have entered non valid Zip Code. please enther only numbers.\n\n";
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function validateCheckBox(x) {
  if (!x.terms.checked) {
    alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="container">
      <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <form name="registration" onsubmit="return validate(this)" action="add.php" method="post">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Fname" autofocus placeholder="Your first name..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Last Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Lname" placeholder="Your last name..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>E-mail</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Your Email..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Your Gender</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="radio" value="Male" name="Gender">Male
              <br>
              <input type="radio" value="Female" name="Gender">Female
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Phone Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Your D.O.B.:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-20">
              Day:<input type="text" name="Day" size="2" maxlength="2" placeholder="5"> Month:
              <input type="text" name="Month" size="2" maxlength="2" placeholder="10"> Year:
              <input type="text" name="Year" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="1995">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>What Hand are you?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="radio" value="Right" name="Hand">Right
              <br>
              <input type="radio" value="Left" name="Hand">Left
              <br>
              <input type="radio" value="Unknown" name="Hand">Unknown
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Street Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-20">
              <input type="text" name="StreetNumber" placeholder="Your Street Number..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Street Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Street" placeholder="Your Street Name..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Subburb</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Subburb" placeholder="Your Subburb..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Postcode</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Zip" placeholder="Your Postcode..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>State</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <select name="State">
          <option value="Victoria" selected>Victoria</option>
          <option value="SouthAustrailia">South Austrailia</option>
          <option value="WesternAustrailia">Western Austrailia</option>
          <option value="NorthernTerretory">Northern Terretory</option>
          <option value="Queensland">Queensland</option>
        </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>I Agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <label class="containerCheckBox">Agree 
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>

</body>

</html>
```

It is always a good idea to trim your text data (e.g. - remove leading and trailing space characters) unless you want to allow leading and trailing space characters.

Comment: What do u mean with trailing space characters?

Comment: if someone adds "   some data   ", you should consider trimming the leading and trailing spaces using the trim() method to yield "some data", unless you want to permit such.  If you don't force it, your length tests on values could cause problems with your validation.

Comment: Here are some changes I made that you may want to note:  (1) I pass the form to the validate() function using the [this] reference in the onSubmit event, (2) the [validated] variable could actually be local to the validate() function, initially it was part of your issue, but now I return [false] or [true] explicity in your various validation functions AND determine the final result through a single line of code. (3) I trim the text values that you validate using x.[input name].value = x.[input name].value.trim()

Answer (score 0):

```js
var errorStr = "" //initialize the errorStr
var trueOrFalse = true

function validate() {
  //initialises all of the variables which are going to be used
  //alert("hello")

  var character = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"
  var temp2
  var difnumbers = "0123456789"
  var temp3

  x = document.registration

  validateFname(x);
  //alert("a")
  validateLname(x);
  //alert("c")
  validateEmail(x);
  //alert("d")
  validateGender(x);
  //alert("e")
  validatePhone(x);
  //alert("f")
  //validateDOB(x);
  //alert("g")
  validateStreet(x);
  //alert("h")
  validateSubburb(x);
  //alert("i")
  validateZipCode(x);
  //alert("j")
  validateCheckBox(x);

  //this will display all of the error messages at the same time.
  if (!trueOrFalse) {
    alert(errorStr);
    errorStr = "";
  }
  //alert("end")

  return trueOrFalse
}

function validateFname(x) {
  //Vallidation for the Firstname
  if (x.Fname.value == "") {
    {
      errorStr = errorStr + "It seems like you havn't entered you're First Name. Please have another look.\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < x.Fname.value.length; i++) {
      temp2 = x.Fname.value.substring(i, i + 1)
      if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
        errorStr = errorStr + "It looks like you have entered a non Alphabetical character into you're First Name.\n\n"
        trueOrFalse = false
      }
    }
  }
}

function validateLname(x) {
  if (x.Lname.value == "") {
    errorStr = errorStr + "It seems like you havn't entered you're Last Name. Please have another look.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Lname.value.length; i++) {
    temp2 = x.Lname.value.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
      errorStr = errorStr + "It looks like you have entered a non Alphabetical character into you're Last Name.\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
  }
}

function validateEmail(x) {
  var test = x.Email.value.indexOf("@")
  //if didn't find @
  if (test == -1) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "Please enter a valid E-Mail.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  //if @ is the first character
  if (test == 0) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "The E-Mail you have Entered is not valid. The '@' can't be the first Character.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  //if @ is the last character
  if (test == (x.Email.value.length - 1)) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "The E-Mail you have Entered is not valid. The '@' can't be the last Character.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
}

function validateGender(x) {
  if (!x.Gender[0].checked && !x.Gender[1].checked) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "Please select a gender\n\n"

    trueOrFalse = false
  }
}

function validatePhone(x) {
  //validation for the mobile number
  if (x.Phone.value == "") {
    errorStr = errorStr + "You haven't inputted a phone number (e.g. 0420 111 111.)\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  if (x.Phone.value.length != 10) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "please input a valid number length(10 Digits).\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Phone.value.length; i++) {
    temp3 = x.Phone.value.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (difnumbers.indexOf(temp3) == -1) {
      errorStr = errorStr + "Sorry, you have entered non valid Phone number. Please enter only numbers.\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
  }
}

function validateStreet(x) {
  //this validates the city
  if (x.Street.value == "") {
    errorStr = errorStr + "You haven't entered your Street, please enter your Street.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Street.value.length; i++) {
    temp2 = x.Street.value.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
      errorStr = errorStr + "Sorry, you have entered a number. Your Street cannot contain a number. Please re-enter .\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
  }
}

function validateSubburb(x) {
  //this part checks the street upon its entered values
  if (x.Subburb.value == "") {
    errorStr = errorStr + "You haven't entered your Street name, please enter your Subburb.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Subburb.value.length; i++) {
    temp2 = x.Subburb.value.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (character.indexOf(temp2) == -1) {
      errorStr = errorStr + "Sorry, you have entered a number. Your Street name cannot contain a number. Please re-enter your Subburb.\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
  }
}

function validateZipCode(x) {
  //validation for the mobile number
  if (x.Zip.value == "") {
    errorStr = errorStr + "You haven't inputted a Zip Code (e.g. 0420.)\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  if (x.Zip.value.length != 4) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "please input a valid Zip Code length(4 Digits).\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < x.Zip.value.length; i++) {
    temp3 = x.Zip.value.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (difnumbers.indexOf(temp3) == -1) {
      errorStr = errorStr + "Sorry, you have entered non valid Zip Code. please enther only numbers.\n\n"
      trueOrFalse = false
    }
  }
}

function validateCheckBox(x) {
  if (!x.terms.checked) {
    alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="container">
      <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <form name="registration" onsubmit="return validate()" action="add.php" method="post">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Fname" autofocus placeholder="Your first name..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Last Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Lname" placeholder="Your last name..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>E-mail</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Your Email..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Your Gender</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="radio" value="Male" name="Gender">Male
              <br>
              <input type="radio" value="Female" name="Gender">Female
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Phone Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Your D.O.B.:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-20">
              Day:<input type="text" name="Day" size="2" maxlength="2" placeholder="5"> Month:
              <input type="text" name="Month" size="2" maxlength="2" placeholder="10"> Year:
              <input type="text" name="Year" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="1995">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>What Hand are you?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="radio" value="Right" name="Hand">Right
              <br>
              <input type="radio" value="Left" name="Hand">Left
              <br>
              <input type="radio" value="Unknown" name="Hand">Unknown
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Street Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-20">
              <input type="text" name="StreetNumber" placeholder="Your Street Number..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Street Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Street" placeholder="Your Street Name..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Subburb</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Subburb" placeholder="Your Subburb..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>Postcode</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <input type="text" name="Zip" placeholder="Your Postcode..">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>State</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <select name="State">
          <option value="Victoria" selected>Victoria</option>
          <option value="SouthAustrailia">South Austrailia</option>
          <option value="WesternAustrailia">Western Austrailia</option>
          <option value="NorthernTerretory">Northern Terretory</option>
          <option value="Queensland">Queensland</option>
        </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
              <label>I Agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <label class="containerCheckBox">Agree 
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>

</body>

</html>
```

You have to reset the `errorStr=""` after calling `alert(errorStr)` or else it will really keep adding up messages as you call up the validation multiple times without resetting `errorStr` variable.

Comment: Don't forget about the trueOrFalse value as well; both of these variables need to be re-initialized either at the beginning of the main validation function OR where @mngkvn suggested.

Comment: [character] and [difnumbers] may need to be global variables like errorStr and trueOrFalse (hence, declared in the same area outside of any functions).

Answer (score 0):

I would have left this as a comment, but that does not allow for code formatting. This style of form validation is antiquated and *very* labour-intensive.

Have a look at [HTML5 form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation), which will reduce the amount of code you have to write (and thus possibility for bugs) enormously.

This is not a library, this is an in-built HTML5 feature ([support](https://caniuse.com/#search=form%20validation)).

For example, this whole function

```
function validateEmail(x) {
  var test = x.Email.value.indexOf("@")
  //if didn't find @
  if (test == -1) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "Please enter a valid E-Mail.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  //if @ is the first character
  if (test == 0) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "The E-Mail you have Entered is not valid. The '@' can't be the first Character.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
  //if @ is the last character
  if (test == (x.Email.value.length - 1)) {
    errorStr = errorStr + "The E-Mail you have Entered is not valid. The '@' can't be the last Character.\n\n"
    trueOrFalse = false
  }
}
```

can be replaced by [`input[email]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email):

```js
const email = document.getElementById("emailInput");

email.addEventListener("input", event => {
  // Only for illustration, you don't need to subscribe to events to get this.
  console.log(email.validity);
})
```

```html
<input type="email" id="emailInput" required>
```

That field will then be decorated with a [`ValidityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) with lots of properties you can check for to generate custom errors. You can also use the CSS classes which are added to those fields automatically to style the inputs if you want and [give in-place custom errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Customized_error_messages).

You can also use the `pattern=""` attribute to set a custom pattern (if, for example, you want to enforce that email addresses have a dot after the `@`, which is actually not required by the specification).

You also seem to want to ensure that a user doesn't enter series of repeated characters "111111" for values. That is (mathematically, not meant to be insulting) naive, because they could enter nonsense in lots of ways, like "12121212" for a phone number.

If you still want to do that, write one helper function:

```
var checkRepeats = input => input.every(character => character == input[0])
```

And call that when you need it with [`setCustomValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_API's_element.setCustomValidity()).

In short, using fancier features will result in far, far less code, fewer bugs, and a better user experience.

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, if it works consistently and natively.  I also think that perhaps he should break out of some of the validation logic sooner (e.g. - when value==null/empty, report that, but avoid additional messages related to that field (like invalid chars, etc.).

Comment: @codemaker I'll add the browser support (it's universal). It's been around for a while. The usefulness of this is that it allows for all sorts of fun stuff like validation-rule-based input CSS styling without having to do anything extra. I use it extensively (when I'm in a framework-less environment).

Comment: @codemaker I logged the whole `ValidityState` object to show the additional information it provides, like "too short", or "invalid", which can trivially be used to generate meaningful, specific messages.